# Is it okay to display a page in a language taken from a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, cookies

The [Rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/i18n.html#storing-the-locale-from-the-session-or-cookies) says:

> You may be tempted to store the chosen locale in a session or a cookie. However, do not do this. The locale should be transparent and a part of the URL. This way you won't break people's basic assumptions about the web itself: if you send a URL to a friend, they should see the same page and content as you. A fancy word for this would be that you're being RESTful. Read more about the RESTful approach in Stefan Tilkov's articles. Sometimes there are exceptions to this rule and those are discussed below.

But a [couple of screens above](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-user-preferences), it teaches how to set locale from user preferences. Which equals to setting it from a cookie.

I saw no such warnings in Django documentation. And although you probably can avoid it, [storing it in a cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.set_language) seems like a recommended way.

Is it okay to display a page in a language taken from a cookie? To cookie or to not?

And if it's okay, what do I do with the urls? Do I still need different urls for different languages, even so the language gets overriden by cookies?

**UPD** To make it clear I didn't imply which is better, Rails or Django. It's just that those are the 2 frameworks I examined to find the answer. And the fact that Django suggests to store it in a cookie is my speculation. Now that I think about it, it probably doesn't. It just supports both options.

Also, by "different urls for different languages" I meant this:

- Language is determined by url. Each versions of a page has its own url (en.example.com, or example.com/en, or example.com/?lang=en).

Comment: OK according to who?

Comment: @TylerH To good design principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several questions here.  First, the locale cookie question.

The main question to ask is if the URL you are working with is specific to a certain user, or something that might be shared or viewed by multiple users.  If it is specific to a user (their settings page, or some other private page that they can only see after logging in) then it makes perfect sense that the locale is part of their settings.  Cookie is very reasonable here.

However, if the locale is part of a page that multiple users would see, then you want to include the locale as part of the URL.  So that if I send you https://blah.blah.foo/check/this/out?response=foo&lang=EN you will see exactly what I am seeing.

As far as handling different URLs for different languages, you generally keep the same routes/views and lean on rails's I18N to handle multiple languages.  But like everything else, you can do it however makes the most sense for your app :)

Comment: I meant "different urls for different languages" in a framework-agnostic way. Does a site have to define/respond to urls that contain a language (if using a cookie is okay)? Which you covered in the first part.